# How do I embed code to appear on every product page in shopify?

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I am trying to add some Google Analytics related code (addition to the standard code) on every product page. I tried adding it to the bottom of the "product.liquid" file but it doesn't seem to pull through to the live site. Could it be to do with some special Shopify security function that stops unusual looking javascript from being used?

Kind regards,
Benet Hitchcock.

Comment: I would contact Shopify.

Comment: Can you update your question with in the code you are adding to your product.liquid file? If it's formatted and saved correctly, then it should be no problem to have placed on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this through your app. You need to take read|write_theme scope at the time of installation of you app now go to theme setting->temeplate editor

Open themes.liquid file and paste your code there

Then its appears on all page